# Matcher lookingAt method matching empty String

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a `Matcher` instance to match patterns at the start of some input using the `lookingAt()` method.  `lookingAt()` is however returning true when I create a `Pattern` from an empty String and try to match it with a non-empty (trimmed) String.

Firstly, this is as I expect it:

```
String field = "Dave went to Alabama"

String escapedQuery = Pattern.quote("Dave went");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(escapedQuery, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);
// matcher.lookingAt() == true
```

However, this pattern generated from an empty String also returns true:

```
String escapedQuery = Pattern.quote("");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(escapedQuery, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);
//matcher.lookingAt() == true
```

All Strings involved have been trimmed before any Patterns are compiled.

Can anyone point me as to what I'm missing here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty regular expression matches all strings. If you want a regular expression that matches only the empty string, you'll need something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string, and `$` matches the end. The expression `^$` therefore matches strings that begin and then immediately end; i.e., the empty string.

Of course there are better ways to match the empty string. These spring to mind:

```
string.length() == 0
string.equals("");
```

Comment: I do like that "CASE_INSENSITIVE"!

Comment: I'm just following his example. :)

Comment: @Pshemo, I did not. The empty regular expression `//` matches all strings except for the null string. The null string, of course, can't be matched by any regular expression.

Comment: @Pshemo: String.matches is a special case, as it has an implicit `^` before and an implicit `$` after its argument. The empty string in that case doesn't map to the empty regular expression as it does with `Pattern.compile("")`.

Comment: OK, I guess we use different words to describe same thing. To avoid confusion with `String#matches` method I would probably say it like "The empty regular expression is searching for empty strings and since each string has empty string before it this code returns true for all strings". But it is your answer so it is your call. I will remove my comments since they probably don't add any valuable info.

Comment: @Welbog "The null string, of course, can't be matched by any regular expression." This isn't correct, since `"".matches("")` returns `true`.

Comment: @laune: "" is the empty string. The null string is distinct from the empty string. Think of a string as a set of characters. The empty string is a set with zero elements. The null string is not having a set at all.

Comment: @Welbog See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string, I'm in good company. - Do you also speak of a "null integer", a "null double", a "null character" (oh, my, another misunderstanding), a "null object"? Simply calling it **null** is preferable, since null doesn't have a class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consistency matter. Empty patterns are like empty strings, and if you try

```
System.out.println( "abc".indexOf("") );
```

you'll see that this is found at offset 0.

Clearly there is a substring of length 0 to be found at many places within a string of length > 0, and even in a string of length 0!